# How to create a "forced" lightbox, i.e. a "Pause" screen with content behind it

Tags: php, javascript, lightbox, block

I see Google doing this all the time. They are able to successfully create a lightbox that can't be ignored... and even though the content behind it is visible (i.e. a form you would otherwise be able to fill out), you cannot do anything with that content-- I've even tried using the Document Inspector to get around the forced lightbox, and it's very, very difficult.

So, I'm not as concerned with the validation of the content BEHIND the box as I am with really nailing home the point that the lightbox is "not to be messed with". In other words, what's the best way to show a box that the user isn't supposed to (or able to) click out of until they've completed the action thereupon, while simultaneously showing a desaturated or partially whitened-out (but still visible) version of the content behind it?

As I said, I can code to make certain that the content behind the box isn't actually usable unless the requisite actions have been completed (so even if they get around it, it won't be functional). I just want to be a bit more stern with the people out there (like me) who will try simple things like a JavaScript blocker to prevent the content from lightboxing properly. Ideally, the solution I'm looking for would be cross-platform compatible and difficult to get around. I'm open to any type of solution that can be done via open-source code.

Comment: Do a search for javascript modal dialog box. You will see many solutions to this.

Comment: You seem a bit confused about what you're asking: on the one hand you're talking about allowing for a JavaScript blocker, but on the other hand if JavaScript is blocked how would the lightbox (or, more properly, "modal dialog box") be displayed in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://fancybox.net/

has an option `hideOnContentClick: false` that will only allow the user to click the "X" button in the fancy box to hide it. You could hide the "X" close button through css or take it out completely and have a javascript call when the user has completed all the fields or submitted to close the box.

Hope I read your question right.

Answer (score 1):

Most lightbox features come with this. However, making your own, it's a 2 layer concept. 2 DIV's basically. One which spans to all 4 corners of the open browser. Most people will give it a color or something black and then set a transparency on it. After that you set a high zindex on it. Once you have that one in place you put another DIV inside of that one to mimic your lightbox needs. This way a user can't just click around the box and get to what they want. All in all though, javascript and CSS are easy to work around, all you need is a developer tool in your browser to just turn them off leaving you with only the raw form.

*EDIT*
Bottom line is, anything in the client side is always fallible. If someone's determined enough they will get around it. And if your doing it as a means of security from bots, that won't work, if someone who controls the bot is smart enough. I'm only saying this cause I hope there's not any false hopes that it will be a means to an end of a problem some how. Don't get me wrong it will detour many to a point, but those with malicious intent will break the concept easily with a little XSS or other various measures designed to break client-side only concepts.

*EDIT 2*
Both Jquery UI and Bootstrap from Twitter have good Dialog concepts that a normal every day user of your site won't be able to smash around easy.